Showing that a function $u_\epsilon\rightharpoonup0$ in the $L^2$ norm, as $\epsilon\to0$.

Let $u : \mathbb{R} \to [-1, 1]$ be defined by $u(y) = \cos(2\pi y)$.
Set $u_\epsilon(x) = u\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)$ for $x \in (a,
> b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$. Show that $ u_\epsilon \rightharpoonup 0 $ in $ L^2(a, b) $ as $ \epsilon \to 0 $.

Solution
With  $u(y)$,  set $y=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$,
The $L^2$ norm for $u_\epsilon$ is given by
$$
||{u_\epsilon}||_{L^2(a,b)} = \left( \int_a^b \left| \cos\left( 2\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \right|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.
$$
Since $ \left| \cos \left( 2\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \right|^2 $ simplifies to $ \cos^2\left( 2\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) $, we use the trigonometric identity:
$$
\cos^2\left( 2\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \cos\left( 4\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \right).
$$
Now we solve the integral:
$$
\int_a^b \cos^2\left( 2\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \, dx = \int_a^b \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \cos\left( 4\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \right) \, dx.
$$
Splitting this into two integrals:
$$
\int_a^b \frac{1}{2} \, dx + \int_a^b \cos\left( 4\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \, dx.
$$
And we obtain
$$
\int_a^b \frac{1}{2} \, dx = \frac{b - a}{2}.
$$
The second integral,
$$
\int_a^b \cos\left( 4\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \, dx,
$$
oscillates rapidly as $ \epsilon \to 0 $. Since the oscillations average out over the interval $ (a, b) $, the integral tends to zero. So if we take the limit, we obtain
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_a^b \cos\left( 4\pi \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) \, dx=0,
$$
So we have only the first integral, and hence the norm on the open interval $(a,b)$ is:
$$
||{u_\epsilon}|| = \sqrt{ \frac{b - a}{2}} = C \ \ \ \forall b>a.
$$
But this shows that $u_\epsilon$ converges to some constant on the open interval (a,b) in the $L^2$ norm, and not zero.
Any ideas what went wrong here?
Thanks

Either ther is a typo in your source or you have mis-typed the definition of $u_{\epsilon}$.

Yes, I found a typo: it should be  $u_\epsilon \rightharpoonup 0$. I corrected it.

Weak convergence of $u_{\epsilon}$ is special case of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Thanks! Any interest  in providing a solution?

Wait are you trying to show weak convergence to zero? The norm itself is only weakly lower semi continuous so it can converge to a constant and yet the weak limit can have norm zero

@SBK how can that be shown?  I have no idea what to do but this approach..

@Superunknown Perhaps you have read/been shown the definition of weak convergence before being asked to show something converges weakly to zero? (It's hard to understand how or why you could be trying to show something like this and also have no idea how to go about it). Maybe read a proof of the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma and that would give a good set of hints.
